# When using vector notation, why do I get double braces around my fractions?

Tags: brackets, vector

I am trying to format a vector gradient with two fractions in it but unfortunately I get it displayed with double braces around the two fractions. Here's my LaTeX:

```latex
\nabla f = \left(
\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}  \\
 \frac{\partial l}{\partial x_2}  \\
\end{pmatrix} \right)
\\
```

[image: vector gradient]

I would like to have only one brace around the two fractions.
How would I have to format it then?

Comment: `pmatrix` already makes the **p**arentheses. You don't need `\left` and `\right` there.

Comment: Note that there is something wrong with your font setup: the subscript numbers are too large.

Answer (score 5):

From the `amsmath` documentation:

> The `amsmath` package provides some environments for matrices beyond the basic
>   `array` environment of LaTeX. The `pmatrix`, `bmatrix`, `Bmatrix`, `vmatrix` and
>   `Vmatrix` have (respectively) `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `||`, and `|| ||` delimiters built in. For naming consistency there is a `matrix` environment sans delimiters.

Thewrefore, when using the `pmatrix` environment you need no `\left(` and `\right)`.